# Как организовать видеозвонки на MODx?

Tags: modx, webrtc

Может кто-то сталкивался с потребностью сделать видеозвонки на MODx. Существуют ли какие-то проверенные решения? Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом.

Comment: почему modx? почему не wordpress? drupal?

Comment: MODx, т.к. я хорошо с ней работаю) Но вообще не принципиально. Можно у другую CMS

Comment: Это был сарказм. Друг, ну реально, неужели твоих знаний недостаточно для того, чтобы понять, что сервис WebRTC невозможно сделать на PHP? Даже если кто-то напишет статью о том, что это получилось, обычно такие поделки ни у кого не доходили до продакшена. Если и получится что-то  сделать, то это будет несколько недель а может месяцев потрачены на то, чтобы связать два компьютера между собой, когда там появится третий клиент, ты поймешь, что сервер уже не вывезет четвертого.

Comment: Эм, я ничего про PHP не указывал в своем вопросе.
Существуют ли решение для MODx с целью осуществления видеозвонков? Вот как звучал мой вопрос. Нет никаких ограничений написать приложение на React и организовать связку Nginx + WebSockets + WebRTC + MODx

Comment: А при чем там React и Nginx?